# Fixing the position of a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am starting a winform application[.NET 3.5, C#], where in the the main form of the application starts at a particular specified location. Am calling the following code in the constructor for this

```
    private void SetFormPosition()
    {
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
        this.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;            
    }
```

After the application starts, I would like to keep the location of the form fixed throughout the application lifetime.

Perhaps, I could 'tap' the Location event changed but am not sure if that would be very elegant.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason this is not easy and that methods of doing so are not readily provided is that you are trying to prevent some very fundamental UI functionality, that of a user being able to move the window and organise their desktop to their preference.  There has to be a very good reason for doing this.

Comment: +1 AdamRalph...don't mess with a users ability to move/resize/close/kill/annihilate your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with others that you probably shouldn't be doing this, but if you must, read on.

You can override the SetBoundsCore method and prevent any movement. We use this to prevent vertical resizing on some UserControl implementations (such as those that contain a ComboBox or other fixed height control), but it is also responsible for the location changing.

The following should get you started:

```
    protected override void SetBoundsCore(
             int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        x = this.Location.X;
        y = this.Location.Y;
        //...etc...
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
    }
```

Comment: I'm glad you answered this question. For all we know, a client may have requested an app be built that cannot be moved around. I have had stranger requests.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the FormBorderStyle to None. This has the added benefit of removing the bar at the top of the window that would give users a false sense that they should be able to move the window.

Comment: Umm... am not sure if the client will be happy. We show some vital information in the title bar!!

Comment: This information couldn't be put in a label at the top of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

`Location = new Point(this.Width,this.Height);`

Comment: To get more impact in your answer, you must explain what was wrong for you, and explain why it should be working after your suggestion.