# How to prevent users from changing the location of windows

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing the position of a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511752/fixing-the-position-of-a-form)

in my application some forms must be not moving by users.
how can i disable move forms another location.

i put that code on form_load

this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = string.Empty;

when form's title is empty form cant be move another location.
but i want to keep form title.

is there a way?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511752/fixing-the-position-of-a-form

Comment: This sounds like a very un-userfriendly thing to do. Are there no other design options? What are you actually doing?

Comment: @TheMuyu please come to this thread and explain what made you ask the question in question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283375/different-screenshots-decorated-with-almost-same-words/283379?noredirect=1#comment141822_283379

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but you can do something like in following code to avoid changing form current location :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pt = this.Location;
    }

    private Point pt;
    private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Location = pt;
    }
```

hope this help.